# cannot import name 'Input' from 'tensorflow.keras.models'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am running TensorFlow 2.0 GPU (CUDA), Keras, & Python 3.7 in Windows 10. i am getting the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2fd313bcdf5e> in <module>
      9 from tensorflow.keras.initializers import RandomNormal
     10 from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
---> 11 from tensorflow.keras.models import Input
     12 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
     13 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose

ImportError: cannot import name 'Input' from 'tensorflow.keras.models' (C:\Users\Syd_R\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\api\_v2\keras\models\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 7):

It should be `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input`.

Comment: Now it giving me a bunch of errors:                                                                           UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-d7f4e2c99b6d> in <module>
    242 gan_model = define_gan(g_model, d_model, image_shape)
    243 # train model
--> 244 train(d_model, g_model, gan_model, dataset)
   
 
UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.

Comment: `This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.` - That's your hint.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Input
```

Answer (score 0):

They change location in newer version:
`from tensorflow.keras import Input`